# Combine rows with max id and min id in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have this table that save Entrance Employees

```
IO_Id   Employee_Id   EnterDate    EnterTime    ExitDate    ExitTime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          1          11/20/2018   08:00      11/20/2018     09:00
2          1          11/20/2018   09:10      11/20/2018     09:20
3          1          11/20/2018   09:30      11/20/2018     10:00
4          2          11/20/2018   09:30      11/20/2018     11:00
5          1          11/21/2018   10:00      11/21/2018     11:30
```

How i can select this result that any row have firstEnterTime  , fistExitTime , LastEnterTime, LastExitTime  for all date and all Employees

```
IO_Id   Employee_Id   EnterDate    firstEnterTime       fistExitTime  LastEnterTime    LastExitTime
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          1          11/20/2018         08:00                 09:00         09:30            10:00
4          2          11/20/2018         09:30                 11:00         09:30            11:00
5          1          11/21/2018         10:00                 11:30         10:00            11:30
```

Comment: Please show your attempts at solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below using min() and max() aggregation

```
select min(IO_Id) as IO_Id,Employee_Id,EnterDate as first_EnterDat,
min(EnterTime) as first_EnterTime,min(ExitTime) as fistExitTime,max(EnterTime) as last_EnterTime,max(ExitTime) as lasEtxitTime
from tablename
group by Employee_Id,EnterDate
order by IO_Id
```